# Backbone View injected links reload Site

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

After rendering a Backbone View I inject HTML generated with jQuery. This HTML also includes links within the application. If you click those links they reload the site.

How can I bind those links so they will trigger the router and don't reload the site?

Comment: Could you post code for the Router and relevant html tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind a click event to those links and call [`Router.navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate). It's important that you `return false` from your event handler as this will prevent the borwser to actually follow the link. Another important thing is to pass `trigger: true` to actually have your router execute (otherwise it will only change the url displayed in the address bar).

```
events : {
    'click a.changeView' : 'changeView'
},

changeView : function(e) {
    Router.navigate(e.target.href, { trigger: true });
    return false;
}
```

Also, you might have to tweak your `href` a bit if it contains protocol, domain, etc... for instance if your `href` is `http://mydomain.com/mypage` you might need to pass only `mypage` to the router.